# The continuity of $f(z)=\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}\frac1{|z|^2}(\operatorname{Re}z)^2(\operatorname{Im}z);&z\ne 0\\0;&z=0\end{smallmatrix}\right.$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

It is an advance complex question… Need you suggestion kindly help me to describe the continuity of this $f(z)$ at all point of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I've edited your title to look more readable (although not perfect). You can edit your question (click "edit" just below it to do so) to actaully write out the function in the question itself, and describe your own work so far on the problem, so that we know how much you know, and can be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $z=x+iy$ and so the top part of the equation becomes $f(x+iy)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$. Can you use this to determine the continuity of $f$ at $z=0$? i.e. when $(x,y)=(0,0)$?